# Call javascript function every second

Tags: javascript, function

I'm trying to learn javascript, buy now when I try to repeat a function, it won't seem to work.

This is my function:

```
    function heyhey(el){
    el.style.position = "absolute";
    el.style.top = Math.floor(Math.random()*document.body.clientHeight);
    el.style.left = Math.floor(Math.random()*document.body.clientWidth);
  }
  heyhey(document.getElementById('random'));
  //random is the id of my html div
```

This works, but I want the function to be called every second

What I've tried to repeat the function:

```
    function heyhey(el){
            el.style.position = "absolute";
            el.style.top = Math.floor(Math.random()*document.body.clientHeight);
            el.style.left = Math.floor(Math.random()*document.body.clientWidth);
            heyhey();
}
          heyhey(document.getElementById('random'));
```

I also tried this:

```
function heyhey(el){
                el.style.position = "absolute";
                el.style.top = Math.floor(Math.random()*document.body.clientHeight);
                el.style.left = Math.floor(Math.random()*document.body.clientWidth);
                setTimeout(heyhey, 5000);
    }
              heyhey(document.getElementById('random'));
              heyhey();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ```
> function heyhey(el)
> ```

The function expects one argument

> ```
> setTimeout(heyhey, 5000);
> ```

You aren't passing it any. Specify the arguments as the third and onwards arguments to `setTimeout`.

```
setTimeout(heyhey, 5000, el);
```

Comment: TIL you can specify `setTimeout` parameters like that.

Comment: [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout): _Note that passing additional parameters to the function in the first syntax does not work in Internet Explorer 9 and below. If you want to enable this functionality on that browser, you must use a polyfill_

Answer (score 1):

if you want to avoid the recursion, you can use [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval) function.

a simple example:

```
var intervalID = window.setInterval(myCallback, 500);

function myCallback() {
  // Your code here
}
```

if you want to stop the execution of your function you have to call the [clearInterval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/clearInterval):

```
clearInterval(intervalID);
```